# having 2 ip's on a debian 7 box

Tags: linux, networking, debian-wheezy

I just installed Debian Wheezy on my homeserver. I want to assign 2 ip's to it on the same network interface, 1 static ip (eth0) and 1 dynamic ip (eth0:1). I know it doesn't make much sense but I need it to test something.

I edited my /etc/network/interfaces to be like this:

```
auto lo eth0 eth0:1
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.178.240
     network 192.168.178.0
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     broadcast 192.168.178.255
     gateway 192.168.178.1


iface eth0:1 inet dhcp
```

when I bring up eth0:1 (ifup eth0:1) I get the following error (eth0 works fine)

> Bind socket to interface: No such device
>
> Failed to bring up eth0:1.

is it even possible to have a dynamic and static ip on the same network adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
post-up /sbin/ip addr add 192.168.178.240/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: Looks like that worked, thx!

Comment: @David what's the output of `ifconfig` now that it works? Put it somewhere to something like pastebin.com.

Comment: @ott http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Ax4rvgMa It doesn't show the static ip but I can ssh to the server via both ip's

Comment: @David that only shows eth0. A simple `ifconfig` without parameters would show eth0:0 and others too.

Comment: Using /sbin/ip adds secondary IPs directly to an interface, which ifconfig doesn't know how to deal with for IPv4 addresses. (The alias-interface style -- eth0:0 -- and the ifconfig utility are deprecated.) '/sbin/ip addr show' will list all the IPs on the interface.

Comment: @ott-- Nop. eth0:0 doesn't have a ip address either. Because I added one to eth0? output of '/sbin/ip addr' http://pastebin.com/LqgbUsar

Comment: @David ok, that shows the 2 addresses.